# failed to start user controllers for cluster c-x6xr5: secrets "cattle-global-data/" not found, requeuing

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, rancher

Rancher Server Setup

Rancher version: 2.7.5
Installation option (Helm Chart) EKS 1.25

Kubernetes version: 1.25
Cluster Type (Local/Downstream):
If downstream, what type of cluster? (Imported EKS1.25):
User Information

What is the role of the user logged in? (Admin/Cluster Owner/)

Describe the bug
[ERROR] error syncing 'all': handler user-controllers-controller: userControllersController: failed to set peers for key all: failed to start user controllers for cluster c-kf2gs: secrets "cattle-global-data/" not found, requeuing

To Reproduce

```
helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-nginx --set controller.service.type=LoadBalancer --version 4.7.1 --create-namespace

kubectl create namespace cattle-system

helm upgrade --install rancher rancher-stable/rancher --namespace cattle-system --version=2.7.5 --set hostname=rancher.xxx.com --set ingress.tls.source=letsEncrypt --set letsEncrypt.ingress.class=nginx --set ingress.ingressClassName=nginx
```

Result

Expected Result

Answer (score 0):

this issue mainly with unauthorized access of AWS IAM user if your IAM user does not have proper permission to create resources then you will get this error.